# Schreibweisen von "siehe oben", besonders in Klammern

Tags: sentence-structure, punctuation, reference

Wie schreibt man "siehe oben", wenn es nach einem Satzende steht? Es geht mir hier um Groß-/Kleinschreibung, Leerzeichen und das Setzen des Punktes.

Beispiel:

> Hier ist oben.
>
> …
>
> Hier ist unten. (Siehe oben.)

Alternativen:

> Hier ist unten (siehe oben).
>
> Hier ist unten (siehe oben.)
>
> Hier ist unten. (Siehe oben)

Und wie schreibt man es (siehe oben) *mitten* im Satz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Frage:** Welche der folgenden drei Alternativen ist richtig?

> 1. Hier ist unten (siehe oben).
> 2. Hier ist unten (siehe oben.)
> 3. Hier ist unten. (Siehe oben)

Und wie schreibt man es mitten im Satz?

**Antwort:** Zunächst einmal sind knappe Referenzangaben wie *siehe oben*, *siehe Abbildung 1* oder *vgl. Mustermann (2000)* keine eigenständigen Sätze. Demnach beginnt das erste Wort wie gewöhnlich, und nach dem letzten Wort steht kein Satzendezeichen. Das gilt auch, wenn sie geklammert im Text auftauchen:

> - Wie bereits erörtert wurde *(siehe oben)*, ist ...
> - Die Druckabhängigkeit der Temperatur *(siehe Abbildung 1)* konnte ...
> - Die Werte weichen zwar von denen aus der Literatur ab *(vgl. z. B. Mustermann, 2000)*, aber ...

Möchte man die Referenzangaben am Ende eines Satzes einschieben, so tut man dies unmittelbar vor dem Satzendezeichen:

> - ... wie bereits erörtert wurde *(siehe oben)*.
> - Die Temperatur steigt mit dem Druck *(siehe Abbildung 1)*.
> - Die Werte weichen von denen aus der Literatur ab *(vgl. z.B. Mustermann, 2000)*!

Richtig ist also Alternative 1 (siehe oben).

Comment: Fußnoten, die sich auf einen gesamten Satz oder Teilsatz (und nicht nur ein einzelnes Wort oder Wortgruppe) beziehen werden idR. hinter dem Satzzeichen als eigenständiger Satz behandelt. Richtig wäre je nach Kontext also auch Version 4: Hier ist unten. (Siehe oben.)

Answer (score 4):

Den Verweis ***siehe oben*** auf eine Textpassage, die weiter vorne im Text steht schreibe ich am Satzende immer klein und schließe nur den davor stehenden Satz mir einem Punkt ab.

> ... hat sich der Klimawandel bestätigt (siehe oben).

Es ist ein Verweis, der als Klammerzusatz den Satz ergänzt und meines Erachtens dazu gehört. Somit soll der Klammerzusatz nicht durch einen Punkt vom Satz getrennt werden und auch nicht innerhalb der Klammer ein Punkt gesetzt werden.

Mitten im Satz schreibe ich ebenfalls klein:

> ... gibt es immer noch Veröffentlichungen (siehe oben), die Zweifel an den ...

Bezüglich der Klein-Großschreibung schreibe ich nur in seltenden Fällen alleinstehende Verweise am Zeilenanfang z.B. in Fußnoten vorn groß:

> Siehe oben S. 148 ff.

Beispiel siehe auch: [*Digitales Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache*](http://www.dwds.de/?q=siehe%20oben)

Answer (score 2):

Hier sind wir schon recht weit ins Gebiet der Typographie und des Schriftsatzes vorgedrungen und haben das Reich der Grammatik und Rechtschreibung wohl fast schon verlassen.

Ich konsultiere in solchen Fällen gerne das schöne Buch "Duden Handbuch Zeichensetzung" und finde auf seinen 254 Seiten etwa folgenden Hinweis:

Im Abschnitt "Die Klammern", Regel 241:

> Wird ein Teil eines Wortes in Klammern gesetzt, setzt man aber meist innerhalb der Klammer einen Bindestrich. (Vgl. aber 248.)

Hier kommt es mir nun gar nicht auf den Inhalt des zitierten Absatzes an. Ich möchte Deine Aufmerksamkeit vielmehr auf den Umgang mit der Anmerkung

> (Vgl. aber 248.)

lenken. Die Autoren haben hier einen Punkt gesetzt.

Der Fall ist sehr ähnlich wie bei deinem "Siehe oben", wo man sich ja auch fragen kann, ob danach ein Punkt gehört oder nicht. (Siehe deine Frage oben.)

Möchtest du nun die Autoren des "Duden Handbuch Zeichensetzung" als Autoritäten auf diesem Gebiet anerkennen, so kannst du dich an ihrem Vorbild orientieren. (Es wäre jedenfalls kein Fehler.)

Die theoretische Argumentation dahinter kreist um die Frage, ob man das in die Klammern Eingefügte als einen eigenständigen Satz betrachtet (dann mit Punkt!), oder ob man es als Teil des vorherigen Satzes ansieht (dann keinen!).

Da "Siehe oben" als ein vollständiger Satz durchgehen kann, wenn auch ein kurzer, kann man hier wohl ohne Schaden einen Punkt setzen. Doch ist dies Interpretationssache. Man kann "siehe oben" auch als eine Beifügung betrachten, die es nicht zur Eigenständigkeit geschafft hat (siehe andere Antwort unten).